# My use of Scipy curve_fit does not seem to work well

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to to fit my data to a Gaussian  using Scipy curve_fit. Unfortunately curve_fit returns 1,1,1.

```
Kp4=fnamer4[615:645]
xk=np.arange(0,1024,1)[615:645]

def func(x, a, x0, sigma):
return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xk, Kp4)
print (popt)
Kp4_fit= func(xk, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
plt.plot(xk, Kp4_fit, 'r',xk, Kp4, 'bs')
```

Kp4 is equal to

```
>>> Kp4
array([23, 27, 20, 26, 22, 22, 26, 29, 32, 19, 34, 26, 29, 24, 32, 41, 27,
   39, 33, 30, 30, 30, 26, 39, 30, 21, 17, 16, 17, 14])
```

The output of the print popt is `[ 1.  1.  1.]`
I have tried curve_fit on much different data before, and it worked fine. Perhaps the problem is that curve_fit cannot fit the data the Gaussian function?! 
Thanks for any help.

The concept I am using for the curve_fit is based on an example from a link bellow:
http://python4esac.github.io/fitting/examples1d.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an initial guess for popt, otherwise the fit starts with [1,1,1] as initial guess which is pretty poor for your dataset!

The following gives reasonable results for me:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xk, Kp4, p0=[20,630,5])
```

The initial guess could be `[np.mean(Kp4), np.mean(xk),5*(max(xk)-min(xk))/len(xk)]`, to have a general starting point.

Don't forget to put `plt.show()` or something similar at the end.

Comment: If the answer works for you, please mark it as solved as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thus, other users will recognize that a) the issue is solved and b) what the solution looks like. Thank you!